# Can changing the audio format (bit depth and bitrate) in Windows damage laptop speakers?

Tags: laptop, audio

I bought this new HP Pavilion dv4 laptop with Beats audio. While trying to tune the audio I reached the section of sound settings where you are allowed to choose sound format (bit depth and sample rate). Then I chose the highest bit depth with highest sample rate available (24-bit 192000 Hz). After applying these settings and listening to some music for 5-10 minutes I again switched the settings back to default. My concern is, have I in this process damaged or harmed my laptop speakers in any way? Can this cause any harm to speakers? The reason I am concerned is that I remember reading warnings on those hi-fi music download sites that high bit depth and sample rate can damage normal speakers.

Here is where I tweaked the settings (click for full-size version):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What you read is nonsense. The speaker only plays whatever signals the sound chip outputs; as long as the chip is not defective (e.g. generating excessive voltage) and the speakers are not abused (e.g. running at very high volumes for a long time), they won't be damaged.

Audio chips today are designed such that they prevent those failure modes (which can harm or damage a speaker).

But probably, you will not hear any benefit from higher bitrates/bit depths: they're useful for recording, but not so much for listening.

Comment: Can it then harm or damage the sound chip?

Comment: Or any other hardware in any way?

Comment: @SegFault I don't think so.